# Android: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f03648).nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtime, uncaught-exception

I am new to android programming. I tried to execute a simple app from one of the tutorials  and it is showing runtime error. I can see in the console messages that its getting installed but while launching, it is throwing the error. I cross verified the entries in manifest file with actual filenames. They all look fine. Below are the error messages from logcat and the activity file. Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Logcat messages

```
01-02 19:54:17.179: D/AndroidRuntime(3088): Shutting down VM
01-02 19:54:17.179: W/dalvikvm(3088): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f03648)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo    {com.vogella.android.intent.implicit/com.vogella.android.intent.implicit.CallIntentsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity    (ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity    (ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run    (ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at com.vogella.android.intent.implicit.CallIntentsActivity.onCreate    (CallIntentsActivity.java:24)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate    (Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity    (ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-02 19:54:17.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     ... 11 more
```

Below is the Activity code

```
package com.vogella.android.intent.implicit;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallIntentsActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner spinnr;
    public static final int URI_INTENT_SCHEME = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        spinnr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.intents, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnr.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        int position = spinnr.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Intent call = null;
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.com"));
            break;
        case 1:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:(+1)1234567899"));
            break;
        case 2:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:(+1)1234567888"));
            break;
        case 3:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:50.123,7.1434?z=19"));
            break;
        case 4:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=query"));
            break;
        case 5:
            call = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            break;
        case 6:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"));
            break;
        case 7:
            call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT,Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/1"));
            break;
        }
        if(call!= null){
            startActivity(call);
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int resultCode, int requestCode, Intent data){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            String result = data.toUri(URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
            Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.call_intents, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Below is the Androimanifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vogella.android.intent.implicit"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CallIntentsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: no root view found, you need `setContentView()` for root view, right below `super.onCreate()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting your `contentview` and the activity crashes with a null pointer exception, in the onCreate method you must set a `contentView` before being able to try to `findViewById`, something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

Now that you have an actual View in your activity, you can go for `spinnr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);`, notice that the crash do not happen when trying to find the view, it happens when you tried to set the adapter, because the reference returned in `findViewById` is null.

Try to read a good book about Android basics if you have the chance to, so you won't bump with simple things...

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It working now. Can you please suggest any good book to learn android development? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Professional Android 4 Application Development, is a very good Book to start with...